# How do I add these variables into my SAS code?

Tags: sas

I am trying to add three variables to my code but am getting the error

```
263  var Subj bmi_init bmi_final bmi_diff;
ERROR: Variable BMI_INIT not found.
ERROR: Variable BMI_FINAL not found.
ERROR: Variable BMI_DIFF not found.
```

Here is my code:

```
DATA dietdata;
            infile 'Downloads/dietdata.dat';
            input Subj $ 1-3 Height $ 4-5 Wt_init 6-8 Wt_final 9-11;
            input(Height,w.d)
            bmi_init = (Wt_init/2.2) / (Height/0.0254);
            bmi_final = (Wt_final/2.2)/(Height/0.0254);
            bmi_diff = bmi_init - bmi_final

RUN;

PROC PRINT data = dietdata;
var Subj bmi_init bmi_final bmi_diff;
RUN;
```

And my infile contents

```
00768155150
00272250240
00563240200
00170345298
00365140128
00467225205
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DATA dietdata;
infile 'Downloads/dietdata.dat';
input Subj $ 1-3 Height $ 4-5 Wt_init 6-8 Wt_final 9-11;
NumHeight = input(Height, 8.);
bmi_init = (Wt_init/2.2) / (NumHeight/0.0254);
bmi_final = (Wt_final/2.2)/(NumHeight/0.0254);
bmi_diff = bmi_init - bmi_final;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reading HEIGHT as character if you want to treat it as a number?  Your BMI formula is wrong. Your conversion from Inches to Meters is wrong. You forgot to square the height in meters.  Your code is missing some semi-colons.

Here is code that works with your example data.  To convert it to reading from your file uncomment the INFILE and RUN statements by removing the * and remove the CARDS statement and the in-line data lines.

```
data dietdata;
*  infile 'Downloads/dietdata.dat';
  input Subj $ 1-3 Height 4-5 Wt_init 6-8 Wt_final 9-11;
  bmi_init = (Wt_init/2.2) / (Height*0.0254)**2;
  bmi_final = (Wt_final/2.2)/(Height*0.0254)**2;
  bmi_diff = bmi_init - bmi_final ;
*run;
cards;
00768155150
00272250240
00563240200
00170345298
00365140128
00467225205
;
```

Result:

```
                                                              bmi_
Obs    Subj    Height    Wt_init    Wt_final    bmi_init     final     bmi_diff

 1     007       68        155         150       23.6169    22.8551     0.76184
 2     002       72        250         240       33.9770    32.6179     1.35908
 3     005       63        240         200       42.6030    35.5025     7.10050
 4     001       70        345         298       49.6059    42.8480     6.75790
 5     003       65        140         128       23.3459    21.3449     2.00108
 6     004       67        225         205       35.3137    32.1747     3.13899
```